# INSERT after new id populated in base table

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two pieces to this question, one will be bonus for me if you can answer.

**Question #1**
I have two SQLITE tables named tbl and tbl_search
Where tbl is a normal table and tbl_search is a FTS4 table

Let's say we are at run#0 of my app, the app runs and starts filling the tbl with data and then at the end, it copies everything from the tbl to tbl_search and job done but, this comes with a performance cost for incremental runs. For incremental runs(run#1), so far, i've been deleting and re-creating the fts table because during normal copy, it used to dump the run#0 items as well, creating duplicate data, plus this was costing a lot on the performance part.

After giving a thought i found 4 methods to tackle this situation:

1) Create a SQL Trigger for tbl to tbl_search copy.

2) Create a temp table in every run and copy its data to tbl_search to avoid duplication and then delete it

3) Use the unique ID's in the ID column of tbl and find the missing ones and replicate only those to tbl_search

4) create another table which will have last run details and use them to put everything after the --AFTER Date column. Let's say last run finished on 04-05-2018 9:40 PM, then replicate everything after that time from tbl to tbl_search.

I found option#3 to be most fruitful in terms of performance and would like to go for it, so how can i do that? Below is an example tbl for reference.

RUN#0

```
ID                    FILENAME                              LABEL_NUMBER
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1              C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          11
2              C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          10
3              C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          8
4              C:/Test_Software/6.avi                          6
5              C:/26.avi                                       10
6              C:/26.avi                                       8
```

RUN#1   (incremental)

```
    ID                    FILENAME                              LABEL_NUMBER
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    7              C:/Test_Software/36.avi                          51
    8              C:/Test_Software/556.avi                         30
```

I would like to run a query like :

```
Select ID from tbl, If (ID not present in tbl_search) INSERT into tbl_search
```

**Bonus Question:** Out of all the methods that i shared, which one is the fastest and best method that i should choose? Please share WHY and How-To as well, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this on my own as i did enough testing now :

**Method #1 : SQL Triggers**

Great method, if you don't have loops to take care of(nested loops)
Painful method if you have trillion loops going on before something can be executed into the tables hence, dis-qualified for me

**Method #2 : Create a Temp Table**

While this is a good method, it won't give you any performance bump, rather 
 there is going to be duplicating effect. Thus, not advisable.

**Method #3 : Use ID**

Best method because of the fact that ID's are created as unique key in the Table, so you can simply query the last id, store id somewhere and then compare the other table starting from the last_known id. Got the best performance benefit here.

**Method #4 : Create another table - Aux Table**

Naah, waste of efforts and resources. not recommended again.

Hope this helps fellow SO folks.

Thanks